# Flash Pro Admob Banners

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, google-play, admob

I'm using Flash Professional CC 2014, I Need to develop android mobile application which includes Google Admob banners.

I found a lot of ANE resources but none seems to be working...

Is there any working ane and please provide me with sample code particularized for Flash Pro.

Comment: Few days ago i successfully implemented this ane: https://github.com/pozirk/ANEAdMob , with a help of this guy: http://vimeo.com/32551703

Comment: Thanx, I tried this one but it didn't work via Flash Pro. is there any sample code specialized for Flash Pro rather than Flash Dev

Comment: Sorry, i don't know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to run this flash file.it is a file by flash pro cc

https://github.com/lilili87222/Admob-ANE/blob/master/demo.fla